# How to create a Camel project using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I am creating a camel project using maven with the follow command:

`mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-java -DarchetypeVersion=2.12.1 -DgroupId=camelinaction -DartifactId=order-router`

Then after using the command I get [ERRORS](http://pastebin.kde.org/pqwthmq9q) and nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [archetype:generate](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) instead of [archetype:create](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html)

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-java -DarchetypeVersion=2.12.1 -DgroupId=camelinaction -DartifactId=order-router`

After this, if you read the solution for the problem you had with log4j in your other post, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks that totally solved my problem ! I don't understand though ... why is this command working and the other one is not? Anyway this is material for yet another question :P 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the archetype is not in the Maven Central directory. You must specify where the archetype should be fetched from, like in:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-java -DarchetypeVersion=2.3-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=cameinaction -DartifactId=order-router -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group
```

Comment: That is odd, specially having in mind that command was suggested in the "Camel in Action" book. Thanks !

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: This command actually doesn't work. But the command given by Grove does. I still gave you +1 because you tried.